# Find the nth element satisfying a condition?

Tags: c++, c++11, find, stl-algorithm

Is there a couple of `std::algorithm/lambda function` to access the `nth` element satisfying a given condition. Because `std::find_if` will access the first one, so is there an equivalend to find the `nth` one ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to create a stateful predicate that will count the number of instances and then complete when the expected count is reached. Now the problem is that there are no guarantees as of how many times the predicate will be copied during the evaluation of the algorithm, so you need to maintain that state outside of the predicate itself, which makes it a bit ugly, but you can do:

```
iterator which;
{  // block to limit the scope of the otherwise unneeded count variable
   int count = 0;
   which = std::find_if(c.begin(), c.end(), [&count](T const & x) {
        return (condition(x) && ++count == 6)
   });
};
```

If this comes up frequently, and you are not concerned about performance, you could write a predicate adapter that created a shared_ptr to the count internally and updated it. Multiple copies of the same adapter would share the same actual count object.

Another alternative would be to implement `find_nth_if`, which could be simpler.

```
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

template<typename Iterator, typename Pred, typename Counter>
Iterator find_if_nth( Iterator first, Iterator last, Pred closure, Counter n ) {
  typedef typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::reference Tref;
  return std::find_if(first, last, [&](Tref x) {
    return closure(x) && !(--n);
  });
}
```

http://ideone.com/EZLLdL

Comment: Would a `mutable` lambda that captured by value work just as well?

Comment: @Yakk: No. The implementation of the algorithm is allowed to copy the predicate so you might end up with the count being updated in different instances of your lambda, which will then lead to the result of the algorithm being wrong (finding the M-th, where `M > N` instance)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas +1 but your approach could be done a little easier with `boost::filter_iterator`, see my answer

Comment: Be careful: when n = 0 initially, it won't return the first matching element.

Comment: I guess it should be `n--` instead of `--n`.

Comment: @Hiura: When `n == 1` it will return the first matching element. That is how I would implement the count, you don't ask for the 0-th matching element and expect to get the first, you ask ofr the 1st matching element and get the first match. Calling with `n == 0` would be undefined, or an additional test could be added that the count is positive, then again the code is for exposition only.

Answer (score 5):

An STL-like function template would be:

```
template<class InputIterator, class NthOccurence class UnaryPredicate>
InputIterator find_nth_if(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, NthOccurence Nth, UnaryPredicate pred)
{
    if (Nth > 0)
        while (first != last) {
            if (pred(*first))
                if (!--Nth)
                    return first;
            ++first;
        }
    return last;
}
```

And if you absolutely want to use the `std::find_if`, you could have something like:

```
template<class InputIterator, class NthOccurence class UnaryPredicate>
InputIterator find_nth_if(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, NthOccurence Nth, UnaryPredicate pred)
{
    if (Nth > 0) {
        do
            first = std::find_if(first, last, pred);
        while (!--Nth && ++first != last);
        return first;
    }
    else
        return last;
}
```

Comment: @Manu343726: It seems that I took too much time to write a good answer :/  Besides, I think my answer _may be_ superior to the accepted answer... ;)

Comment: I normally took much time to write answers too. And while Im writting my long full-explained answer, thousands of two-line answers appear. I understand you :)

Answer (score 4):

David's answer is fine as it is. Let me just point out that the predicate can be abstracted into the iterators by using the [**Boost.Iterator**](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/iterator/doc/index.html) library, in particular the [**`boost::filter_iterator`**](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/iterator/example/filter_iterator_example.cpp) adaptor, which has the advantage that it can be used for a lot more algorithms as well (counting e.g.):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/iterator/filter_iterator.hpp>

template<class ForwardIt, class Predicate, class Size>
ForwardIt find_if_nth(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, Predicate pred, Size n)
{
    auto vb = boost::make_filter_iterator(pred, first, last);
    auto const ve = boost::make_filter_iterator(pred, last, last);
    while (vb != ve && --n)
        ++vb;
    return vb.base();
}

int main()
{
    auto const v = std::vector<int>{ 0, 0, 3, 0, 2, 4, 5, 0, 7 };
    auto const n = 2;
    auto const pred = [](int i){ return i > 0; };
    auto const nth_match = find_if_nth(v.begin(), v.end(), pred, n);

    if (nth_match != v.end())
        std::cout << *nth_match << '\n';
    else
        std::cout << "less than n elements in v matched predicate\n";
}
```

[**Live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=cf71df948b2ec58ee016dce7b70f43f4-25783dc5e0579471d3e326cae35dc982). This will print 2 (the 2nd element > 0, counting starting at 1, so that `find_if` matches `find_if_nth` with `n==1`. If the predicate is changed to `i > 10` or if the nth element is changed to `n = 6`, it will return the end iterator.

Comment: [undefined behavior](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=02ff2c799552600fb174b17d9eacd458-25783dc5e0579471d3e326cae35dc982) -- you need to advance more carefully to match [`find_if_nth`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=2d3e9b6357b3445aa30b374d6a149847-25783dc5e0579471d3e326cae35dc982), which sort of bulks it up.  Do you know a cleaner way to make it safer in case the nth element doesn't exist?

Comment: @Yakk tnx for pointing out the boundary condition. Hadn't really thought about it, will fix it.

Comment: @Yakk I wrote a `find_if_nth` that should behave as the usual `find_if` and return the end iterator when no nth match is found. Because the predicate has been hoisted out of the `for` loop, I still like this solution.

Comment: note that `auto i = 0` is more verbose and slightly less informative than `int i = 0`.  Leftover from when you copied `n` and decremented it?  Try `while (!--n && vb != ve) { ++vb; }`, which means you can pass any decrementable and `bool`able type as your counter.

Comment: @Yakk tnx (again). BTW, I changed the while condition to `vb!=ve && --n)`, so note the reversed operands to `&&` (because `vb` is initialized to the first match, this micro-saves a decrement if no matches exists) and the lack of `!` in front of the decrement (which would be a bug).